# Creating curved imageviews in android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to  create imageviews with curved edges like this diagram

[image]

I want to be able to change the colours of the border at runtime. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Combine [this](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView) with a shape.

Comment: This  may help you to draw and change the stoke color at run-time.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585496/change-shape-border-color-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Define the image view as this and give the background the rectangle shape.

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The rectangle is defined as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Finally, from your code, set the color this way:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) image.getBackground();
    background.setStroke(10, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
```