# Android: How to set stroke color for vector drawable programmatically

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am getting into a trouble with VectorDrawable in Android.
I have a vector drawable file (.xml) and I want to draw it on bitmap. I managed to load this file and draw it on bitmap. I can change its fill color but the problem is that I cannot change its stroke and color.

Any helps would be appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Here is the drawable file:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="312dp"
    android:height="312dp"
    android:viewportWidth="312.7"
    android:viewportHeight="312.699">
<path
    android:pathData="M306.35,266.34c0,22.09 -17.91,40.01 -40,40.01L46.35,306.35c-22.09,0 -40,-17.92 -40,-40.01v-219.99c0,-22.11 17.92,-40 40,-40h220c22.09,0 40,17.9 40,40L306.35,266.34z"
    android:strokeWidth="5"
    android:fillColor="@color/transparent"
    android:strokeColor="#231F20"/></vector>
```

Here is the way I load and fill the shape with blue color:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graph_rounded_rectangle);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: I just tried and got an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Comment: oh ok my bad then..deleting the comment to avoid wrong answer for others. will let you know if i get any other answer for your question. thanks

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Did you find the solution  ? If yes, please share it. How to draw border around <clip-path> ?

Answer (score 8):

As said by [Chris Banes](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes) in [his blog](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#drawable-tinting), you can tint your drawable using support library with the following code:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_asset);

// Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work
// on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);

// We can now set a tint
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
// ...or a tint list
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, myColorStateList);
// ...and a different tint mode
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to add `group` in your `xml` like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="312dp"
    android:height="312dp"
    android:viewportWidth="312.7"
    android:viewportHeight="312.699">
    <group android:scaleX="1.0" android:scaleY="1.0">
        <path
            android:pathData="M306.35,266.34c0,22.09 -17.91,40.01 -40,40.01L46.35,306.35c-22.09,0 -40,-17.92 -40,-40.01v-219.99c0,-22.11 17.92,-40 40,-40h220c22.09,0 40,17.9 40,40L306.35,266.34z"
            android:strokeWidth="5"
            android:fillColor="@color/transparent"
            android:strokeColor="#231F20"/>
    </group>
</vector>
```

Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).

Comment: How can I set stroke for the shape programmatically?

Comment: ah sorry, do you want it programmatically please check it here might can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29204632/3077569

Comment: In my case, I have a VectorDrawable and it cannot be cast to GradientDrawable. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can only access these vector properties in Java API

```
Vector : name
Vector : width
Vector : height
Vector : viewportWidth
Vector : viewportHeight
Vector : tint
Vector : tintMode
Vector : autoMirrored
Vector : alpha
```

for setting stoke of vector (color, size etc) by using java code is not reachable. You have to deal it in drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTint( newColor )` method.

```
VectorDrawable vd = (VectorDrawable)context.getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_hint );
vd.setTint( 0xffff0000 ); //for red color
```

Comment: This works, but it is applied to the entire VectorDrawable. How can I apply it to a part of it (by path/group name) ? I tried to use reflection on VectorDrawableCompat.getTargetByName , but it just returned null