# set ColorFilter for button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to set ColorFilter for Button background. Here is what I have done:

```
Drawable buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shape_rect_stroke);
buttonBackground.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color
                .colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
btnSignIn.setBackground(buttonBackground);
```

shape_rect_stroke.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">


    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

By doing this, I am getting,

[image]

But i want this:

[image]

My xml file is working fine but i want to change the `stroke` color pragmatically, leaving `solid` color as transparent. so i can use same xml for different color button background...

Please suggest me how can i get this. 
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575069/how-to-set-colored-border-on-cardview/36575234#36575234 check my accepted answer

Comment: it is exactly same per your requirement :) change color on ur requirements \

Comment: xml file is working fine but i want to change the `stroke` color pragmatically, leaving `solid` color as transparent. so i can use same xml for different color button background...

Comment: I think that´s what your looking for, you can manipulate the stroke directly by using GradientDrawable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772537/i-need-to-change-the-stroke-color-to-a-user-defined-color-nothing-to-do-with-th

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, thanks.. this was what i exactly needed.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done this by doing this:

```
 GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) btnSignIn.getBackground();
 drawable.setStroke(3, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Transparent button with Border for use below `shape_rect_stroke.xml` file that work for me:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!--apply button background transparent, full opacity-->
        <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
        <!--make button border solid color, nontransparent-->
        <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

**If you want to in programmatically then see below code**

```
  GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(0x00FFFFFF); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
    gd.setCornerRadius(5);
    gd.setStroke(1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    btnSignIn.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: @HelloWorld that mean you have to do this with programmatically?

Comment: thanks!! i have already done this after Opiatefuchs's comment.. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setBackground(setBackgroundDrawable("#3F51B5"));
```

create method to set Stroke Color Run Time:

```
private GradientDrawable setBackgroundDrawable(String strokeColor){
        GradientDrawable shape =  new GradientDrawable();

        shape.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor(strokeColor));
        shape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
        return  shape;
    }
```

Comment: thanks!! i have already done this after Opiatefuchs comment.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### Try this one! Its working like charm

set button android:background="@drawable/shape"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
<corners android:radius="3dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="5px"
    android:color="#03A9F4" />
</shape>
```

Comment: just see above image what i have attached! Do you need anything diff from that?

Comment: no i need this only but i want to change the color defined in stroke pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. But just need to change the PorterDuff.Mode and it will work as you are expecting as you have define it to PorterDuff.Mode.ADD. Just need to change it to PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY. Here is the code:-

```
Drawable buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.shape_rect_stroke);
buttonBackground.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
button.setBackground(buttonBackground);
```

Comment: For better understanding about PorterDuff.Mode you can look at http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html